# IndexError: string index out of range with Python when reading big .txt file

Tags: python, string, format, outofrangeexception

I'm trying to create a beginners level program with Python but I get the following error when reading big .txt files:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P4.py", line 58, in <module>
    maximo = diccionario.get(keyword[1]) #maximo is a variable for the maximum number of ocurrences in a keyword
IndexError: string index out of range
```

For small documents, the program works fine, but for the document provided in class (> 200000 lines, ~2/3Mb) I get an error.

Here is the code I made:

```
file=open("lexic.txt", "r") # abrimos el fichero lexic (nuestro modelo) (probar con este)
data=file.readlines()
file.close()
diccionario = {}

"""
In this portion of code we iterate the lines of the .txt document and we create a dictionary with a word as a key and a List as a value
Key: word
Value: List ([tag, #ocurrencesWithTheTag])
"""
for linea in data:
    aux = linea.decode('latin_1').encode('utf-8')
    sintagma = aux.split('\t')  # Here we separate the String in a list: [word, tag, ocurrences], word=sintagma[0], tag=sintagma[1], ocurrences=sintagma[2]
    if (sintagma[0] != "Palabra" and sintagma[1] != "Tag"): #We are not interested in the first line of the file, this is the filter
        if (diccionario.has_key(sintagma[0])): #Here we check it the word was included before in the dictionary
            aux_list = diccionario.get(sintagma[0]) #We know the name already exists in the dic, so we create a List for every value
            aux_list.append([sintagma[1], sintagma[2]]) #We add to the list the tag and th ocurrences for this concrete word
            diccionario.update({sintagma[0]:aux_list}) #Update the value with the new list (new list = previous list + new appended element to the list)
        else: #If in the dic do not exist the key, que add the values to the empty list (no need to append)
            aux_list_else = ([sintagma[1],sintagma[2]])
            diccionario.update({sintagma[0]:aux_list_else})

"""
Here we create a new dictionary based on the dictionary created before, in this new dictionary (diccionario2) we want to keep the next
information:
Key: word
Value: List ([suggestedTag, #ocurrencesOfTheWordInTheDocument, probability])

For retrieve the information from diccionario, we have to keep in mind:

In case we have more than 1 Tag associated to a word (keyword), we access to the first tag with keyword[0], and for ocurrencesWithTheTag with keyword[1],
from the second case and forward, we access to the information by this way:

diccionario.get(keyword)[2][0] -> with this we access to the second tag
diccionario.get(keyword)[2][1] -> with this we access to the second ocurrencesWithTheTag
diccionario.get(keyword)[3][0] -> with this we access to the third tag
...
..
.
etc.
"""
diccionario2 = dict.fromkeys(diccionario.keys())#We create a dictionary with the keys from diccionario and we set all the values to None
for keyword in diccionario:
    tagSugerido = diccionario.get(keyword[0]) #tagSugerido is the tag with more ocurrences for a concrete keyword
    maximo = diccionario.get(keyword[1]) #maximo is a variable for the maximum number of ocurrences in a keyword
    if ((len(diccionario.get(keyword))) > 2): #in case we have > 2 tags for a concrete word
        suma = float(diccionario.get(keyword)[1])
        for i in range (2, len(diccionario.get(keyword))):
            suma += float(diccionario.get(keyword)[i][1])
            if (diccionario.get(keyword)[i][1] > maximo):
                tagSugerido = diccionario.get(keyword)[i][0]
                maximo = float(diccionario.get(keyword)[i][1])
        probabilidad = float(maximo/suma);
        diccionario2.update({keyword:([tagSugerido, suma, probabilidad])})

    else:
        diccionario2.update({keyword:([diccionario.get(keyword)[0],diccionario.get(keyword)[1], 1])})
```

And finally here are a sample of the input (imagine the same with 200000 lines more):

```
Palabra Tag Apariciones
Jordi_Savall    NP  5
LIma    NP  3
LIma    NC  8
LIma    V   65
Participaron    V   1
Tejkowski   NP  1
Tejkowski   NC  400
Tejkowski   V   23
Iglesia_Catolica    NP  1
Feria_Internacional_del_Turismo NP  4
38,5    Num 3
concertada  Adj 7
ríspida Adj 1
8.035   Num 1
José_Luis_Barbagelata   NP  1
lunes_tres  Data    1
misionero   NC  1
457.500 Num 1
El_Goloso   NP  1
suplente    NC  7
colocada    Adj 18
Frankfurter_Allgemeine  NP  2
reducía V   2
descendieron    V   21
escuela NC  113
.56 Num 9
curativos   Adj 1
Varios  Pron    5
delincuencia    NC  48
ratito  NC  1
conservamos V   1
dirigí  V   1
CECA    NP  6
formación   NC  317
experiencias    NC  48
```

Comment: That simply means some rows are shorter than others or you have empty rows

Comment: @PadraicCunningham and for me it is not a problem if a row is shorter, but the program is not correct and I need to fix the error.

Comment: can you post the full traceback as that will make things a bit more obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments. You write that:

```
create a dictionary with *a word as a key* and a List as a value
```

So your key in the dictionary `diccionario` is a single word. However in your second for loop, you have this:

```
for keyword in diccionario:
    tagSugerido = diccionario.get(keyword[0]) 
    maximo = diccionario.get(keyword[1])
```

This means that you use first letter (i.e. keyword[0]) of an actual keyword (which is a word, based on your comments) and then second letter of the keyword (i.e. keyword[1]) to look for values in dictionary. This is incorrect, i think. Also it seems that `keyword[1]` is out of index, if your keyword is only one letter for some lines.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that tomorrow